# How to set environment variable for google cloud speech API in php

Tags: php, google-cloud-speech

I have installed google cloud SDK and trying set environment variable, so I could not do the configuration for google cloud speech API please help me to understand and integrate google API into my system

I have installed google cloud SDK powershell and tried to set environment variable with folder name i.e:

`set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="[C:\Users\Desktop\s\google speech\My-9ef3b2edbbdb.json]"`

Comment: How are you using PHP ? CGI? Manual command from prompt? Via Apache?

Comment: yaa I'm using Apache

Answer (score 1):

Or use **putenv** from PHP:

```
/** Setting Up Authentication. */
$key_path = '/full/path/to/key-file.json';
putenv( 'GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=' . $key_path );
```

Answer (score 0):

As described in [Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_env.html), you should add to the `.htaccess` file or in the `httpd.conf` file.

```
SetEnv GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS C:\Users\Desktop\s\google speech\My-9ef3b2edbbdb.json
```

After you saved `httpd.conf`, the apache server should be reloaded. Otherwise, the environment variable will not be set in this apache session!

Be careful, the Apache module `mod_env` shall be installed.